# Location of Type3 font being used in my document?

Tags: fonts

When I was looking at the types of fonts being used in my LaTeX document compiled using `pdflatex`, I found one Type3 font called `F209`.

A Google search told me that Type3 fonts are also called `pk` fonts in LaTeX. Upon looking at my log, I saw this entry. `MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\jknappen\ec\dpi600\ectt1200.pk` 
Does anyone know what this font type is and what is actually displayed?

This Type3 font is only displayed when I use the package `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Is it really necessary to use this package as other people have recommended?

Comment: You should install the CM-Super font package (from MiKTeX's package manager) or use the Latin Modern fonts (`\usepackage{lmodern}`).

Comment: Will the `lmodern` interfere with the minionpro package?

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, the font is the typewriter font from `\ttfamily` etc. from the EC fonts.

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but do you know what glyph/glyphs are included in that file?

Comment: @Bluemilk In that case it's better to simply say `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}`, but loading `lmodern` before `minionpro` will do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic installation of MiKTeX doesn't download the Type1 fonts for the Computer Modern fonts in T1 encoding (actually the European Modern fonts are used, but they are very similar to Knuth's CM). Since the compiler doesn't find Type1 fonts, it includes the bitmap version obtained by running Metafont and converts it into a Type3 font.

The required Type1 fonts are provided by the CM-Super package, that you can install with MiKTeX's package manager.

Alternatively you can specify to use the Latin Modern fonts (again very similar to CM), that should be available in the basic installation:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Since this changes also the text fonts, and from your comment I gather that the `minionpro` package doesn't change the monospaced font family, you can do

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{minionpro}
```

so that the second call overwrites the text fonts chosen by the first one.

Another way would be to change only the monospaced font family:

```
\usepackage{minionpro}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
```

as `lmtt` is the name by which Latin Modern Typewriter is known to LaTeX.

Comment: So the only reason why I have been loading Type3 fonts prior to adding this `lmodern` package is because I am using monospaced fonts in my document? If so, that is interesting as I don't recall ever specifying specific areas of the text as monospaced.

Comment: @Bluemilk If the font is included in the PDF, then you have in your document at least a letter in it.

Answer (score 7):

PK fonts are (compressed) bitmap fonts generated from MataFont fonts (metafont only output bitmaps at given resolution, not vector splines), because PDF does not support such fonts, pdfTeX converts them to Type3 fonts (which can contain bitmaps) to embed in PDF files.

So, in short, when you see Type3 fonts in your PDF it is almost certainly because your document is using a font available only in MetaFont format and not Type1.

In this case it is because you are missing Type1 versions of Computer Modern fonts in T1 encoding (by default they are in OT1 encoding), so you may want to install CM-Super fonts that include Type1 versions of them, or use Latin Modern fonts (`lmodern` package) which are an “upgrade” to Computer Modern fonts in Type1 format and many encodings, as mentioned in @egreg’s comment above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nice explanation about why Type3 fonts are loaded. I was weighing between tagging your answer as an accepted answer or egreg's. However, egreg first suggested loading the `lmodern` package before the `minionpro` package, so he gets it :)

Answer (score 0):

I went and had a look at where I could have used a typewriter font. After doing a bit of googling, I realised that the `verbatim` environment uses a typewriter font, which I had used in one section of my paper.

With that in mind, I did a two tests. In the first test, I loaded the `luximono` monospace font package and removed the `lmodern` package. I compiled the file and sure enough, no Type3 font was loaded. The luximono font was of course, loaded.

In the second test, I removed the `luximono` package and removed the `lmodern` package. That is, the file was in the same state as it was when I initially posted this question. Sure enough, the Type3 font was loaded again.

So the take-home message is: When using the verbatim environment, make sure to use the `lmodern` package or some other package which provides monospace fonts, though I am not really sure if I had not used the MinionPro package, if the `lmodern` package is still needed.