Is this summation symbol still around

https://hlma.hanglung.com/getattachment/129a540b-f5d6-4044-ab4e-031362f7a25c/007.pdf
This document seems to be generated by Latex. I would like to use the sum symbol here and I am wondering if anybody knew which distribution it is from or if it is from a particular font. I have checked pretty much all the opentype public math fonts in current texlive distribution and I did not find any font with this sum symbol

How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

Apparently that doesn't work, the name is F76 of type Type 3… this doesn't readily result in a font name

Even if it did, it wouldn't be of much use I reckon. The document is from 2006 and I can only guess it was also written using LaTeX distributions available at the time. So I would say it's a matter of fonts available in those distributions rather than simply the name of the font, hence, my question.

Because LaTeX is extremely backwards compatible, chances are whatever fonts available at that time (if it is in a standard distribution instead of proprietary font) is most likely still in TeX live now.

Looking at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73766/location-of-type3-font-being-used-in-my-document it doesn't look like the obtained font name (which is just F ⟨random number⟩  has anything to do with the original so… might be a difficult case here

Right, some font names make little to no sense. Sometimes I wonder why such aesthetically pleasing fonts were discontinued

My guess is that the document was compiled with LuaLaTeX, the unicode-math package, \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} to set the main math font, and something like \setmathfont[range=\sum, StylisticSet=nn]{<some math font>} to select the summation symbol. I consulted the posting Which OpenType Math fonts are available?, but none of the examples given there generate a summation symbol that's the same as in the screenshot you've provided. That's why I'm guessing it's necessary to come up with a suitable selection for the StylisticSet option.

Have you considered contacting the editorial office of the journal, Hang Lung Mathematics Awards, with your question?

That is an excellent suggestion. I will do that.

@Mico it was typeset with pdfTeX, so definitely not using unicode-math ;).

the document was created with MikTeX. possibly worth bearing in mind since the distribution includes some packages, including fonts, excluded from TeX Live for licensing reasons.

It's the summation sign provided by Anthony Phan's mathabx package.

Check out p. 15 of the documentation https://ctan.org/pkg/mathabx

I think you found the answer @ApoorvPotnis

My current solution (I think this should be placed after all other font related declarations):
\let\div\relax
\let\circ\relax
\let\owns\relax
\let\convolution\relax
\let\diamond\relax
\let\bullet\relax
\let\ocirc\relax
\let\widecheck\relax
\let\emptyset\relax
\usepackage{mathabx}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<->mathx10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'270}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\prodop} {\mathop}{mathx}{'271}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathxintop}  {\mathop}{mathx}{'273}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop} {\mathop}{mathx}{"B6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{mathx}{"B7}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\int}{\DOTSI\mathop{\mathchoice{\mathxintop}{\intop}{\intop}{\intop}}\ilimits@}
\makeatother

Thanks to this comment and some other questions like the following:
Borrowing the integral and summation signs from mathabx package
How do I import these three specific symbols from mathabx?
How to use the symbol \blackdiamond from the mathabx package, without changing the appearance of other symbols?
Ideally, I would like to automatically scale the sum/int/similar symbols and instead of loading mathabx, I could simply import these symbols along with delimiters. For example, the sum symbol is same for both inline and display styles. But for the purpose of this question, this will do.

